# Mongo DB - use value from property as key in second property in query

Tags: mongodb, nosql

In Mongo, I have document:

```
{
 'option': 'b',
 'a' : 'abc'
 'b': 'qaz'
 'c': 'wsx'
}
```

I want to create query to get value of element with key the same as value of element 'option' so the result will be:

```
{
'result': 'qaz'
}
```

How can I create aggregation query in Mongo to get this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      data: { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
      option: "$option"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      data: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$data",
          cond: { $eq: ["$$this.k","$option"] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      result: {
        "$arrayElemAt": [ "$data", 0 ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      result: "$result.v"
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WJkUvu2F8Gr)**